# (no match for operator[])//C++ show me that error when i try to use arrays on my function

Tags: c++

Im trying to use vectors in my function kardexop but it show me an error about the operands and i dont know how to resolve it. (i have tu use vectors due to i need to storage that information)

```
printf("ingrese el tipo de movimiento:\n");
scanf("%s", &kardexinfo[i].tip_mov);
kardexinfo[i].saldo =(kardexinfo,i);
printf("CODIGO ITEM\tNOMBRE DEL ITEM\tCANTIDAD\tTIPO MOV\t SALDO\tTOTAL EN COSTO");
printf("%d\t %s\t %d\t %s\t %d\t %.2f",kardexinfo[i].ingreso.codigo[10],kardexinfo[i].ingreso.nombre[0],kardexinfo[i].cantidad,kardexinfo[i].tip_mov,kardexinfo[i].costo_total);
```

Here i try to use the function but i want to use it with the information of the main function

```
int kardexop(kardex kardexinfo, int item_actual){
    switch(kardexinfo[item_actual].tip_mov){
    case 'I':{
       printf("ingrese la cantidad del items:\n");
       scanf("%d",&kardexinfo[item_actual].ingreso.cantidad);
        /*kardexinfo.saldo=kardexinfo[i].saldo+kardexinfo.cantidad;*/
       for (int cont=0;cont<item_actual;cont++) {
          if ( kardexinfo[cont].ingreso.codigo == kardexinfo[item_actual].ingreso.codigo) {
             kardexinfo[item_actual].saldo += kardexinfo[cont].saldo + kardexinfo[item_actual].ingreso.cantidad;
          }     
       }
       kardexinfo[item_actual].costo = kardexinfo[item_actual].saldo*kardexinfo[item_actual].ingreso.precio;
       kardexinfo[item_actual].saldo += kardexinfo[item_actual].ingreso.cantidad;

       break;
   }
```

there is the error.

[image]

Comment: This isn't a [mre] but `kardex kardexinfo` does not look like an array

Comment: need to see full definition of the `kardex` class. If it is a vector, we need to see the class definition for the type of object it stores.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, The error message states that there is no `[]` operator accepting an `int`. So it is clearly *not* a vector.

Answer (score 1):

1. `kardex kardexinfo` is not an array, unless you defined it as some kind of pointer that points to array. We cannot see that, but judging by error it is not. Read this article about arrays: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/passing-arrays-function
2. `kardex` seems to be custom type (ea. class or struct) which does not have `operator[]` to overload that operator called subscript operator read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/subscripting_operator_overloading.htm
3. Post code of `kardex` class and we could help further. But here is my assumption what you have:

```
class kardex {
public:
   // constructor and member function
private:
   // other variables
   std::vector<int> k;
}
```

In that case you can easily overload subscript operator to access vector's element like this:

```
class kardex {
public:
   // constructor and member function

   int &operator[](int i) {
       return k[i];
   }

   int operator[](int i) const {
       return k[i];
   }
private:
   // other variables
   std::vector<int> k;
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 +1 for suggestion will change the link as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there is little relevant information in your post, but I think I should be able to guess what your problem is.

I assume you have a class like this somewhere in your code:

```
class kardex
{
   ....
};
```

Somewhere else, I assume, you have a a vector of instances of this class:

```
std::vector<kardex> kardexinfo;
```

Now you are trying to create a function `kardexop` that does something with an element in that array. This is where it looks like you are being confused.

In `kardexop` you are trying to access an element in the vector `kardexinfo` like this `kardexinfo[item_actual]`. This would be fine if `kardexinfo` was a vector (or array or something else that accepted `[]` operator), but it isn't. The function signature of of `kardexop` is

```
int kardexop(kardex kardexinfo, int item_actual)
```

That means that inside `kardexop` the variable `kardexinfo` is a single `kardex` element, not a vector. If you want to reference the original vector, you have to pass a reference to a vector *not* a single element:

```
int kardexop(std::vector<kardex> &kardexinfo, int item_actual)
```

The `&` means that a `std::vector<kardex>` is passed as reference, rather than a copy. That is important here, since you are modifying the vector and probably don't intend to restrict the modifications to a copy. It has also
the added benefit that for big objects, passing by reference is generally faster than creating a copy.

As an added note:

I don't know what you expect `kardexinfo[i].saldo =(kardexinfo,i);` to do, but it won't do that.

Comment: LOL I am giving you +1 for trying but I think he has custom class w member value `saldo` beaning balance.

Comment: @KPCT, my snarky comment at the end was not refering to `saldo`, but to `= (kardexinfo,i)`. I am really curious to what OP think it does. So OP, if you are reading this don't feel offended by my snarkiness. Tell us what you think it does, and we may help you out.